# Oxygen isotope ratio and Glaciers

Tags: oceanography, geochemistry, homework, glaciology

The question is basically:

> During the Cretaceous there were no continental    ice    sheets. The ratio
>   of O-18/O-16 in sea water was:
>
> a) Higher than today
>   b) Lower than today

The answer is stated to be b, but it does not make sense as glaciers have a lower <sup>18</sup>O/<sup>16</sup>O ratio and so the ratio should be higher than today. Can someone justify why it's b?

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange! If you need any assistance with the site, please visit [The Help Center](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help). Also, please see [this Meta post on homework questions](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/180/homework-questions). The best possible way to keep a homework question from being closed is to show that you have made a good-faith effort to work the problem before posting here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does make sense.
As you said - glaciers have lower <sup>18</sup>O/<sup>16</sup>O. This is because they have less <sup>18</sup>O overall. Therefore, the oceans have more <sup>18</sup>O. But this is today.

At the Cretaceous there were no continental ice sheets, so what we said previously is not relevant. There are no ice sheets to take all of the <sup>16</sup>O, so it's all in the ocean. This results in a lower overall <sup>18</sup>O/<sup>16</sup>O ratio.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [quite relevant paper](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/310/5752/1293) in *Science* with a fine analysis and interpretation on $\delta$ <sup>18</sup>O evolution during the [Phanerozoic Eon](http://stratigraphy.org/ICSchart/ChronostratChart2015-01.jpg), which quite summarily display how this ratio depend on the sea level among other things.

Full reference here : 
Miller, K. G.; Kominz, M. A.; Browning, J. V.; Wright, J. D.; Mountain, G. S.; Katz, M. E.; Sugarman, P. J.; Cramer, B. S.; Christie-Blick, N. & Pekar, S. F. The Phanerozoic Record of Global Sea-Level Change Science, 2005, 310, 1293-1298

Actually, following this paper, sea level was somewhat higher than today during the late Cretaceous, with a 100 $\pm$ 50 m peak during that period (in the abstract). They established the concept of *a small and ephemeral ice sheet* in Antarctica as well between 100 and 33 Million years. Some significant factors regulating the sea level and oxygen ratios would be, for any given time:

1. Sea Level
2. Average global temperature
3. Tectonic activity and related tectonoeustasy > implying impact on water displacement

Briefly to answer the question, Figure 3 in the paper show the $\delta$ <sup>18</sup>O in all time during the Cretaceous as lower than during recent times - so b) is the answer.

[image: Re-plot of Miller et al. 2005 Figure 3 showing oxygen isotopes and sea level change since 100Ma]

<sub>Redrawn and simplified after Miller et al. 2005</sub>

Comment: I am not sure if it is permitted to show figures stored behind a paywall - if anyone could inform me on such policies and how SE deals with this - well this answer would be more 'graphic' with the actual figure 3... I assume for now that this is not permitted

Comment: In the mean time I added a plot I made using the supplementary material of Miller et al. 2005.

Comment: @plannapus nice one that really does it and really complete the answer IMO

Answer (score 2):

First of all, oxygen isotopes are generally given as <sup>16</sup>O/<sup>18</sup>O so it is confusing the way the questions is asked from a geochemical perspective.  My students typically get confused about this.  But it is very simple to understand if you keep in mind that <sup>16</sup>O is lighter than <sup>18</sup>O.  Evaporation of ocean water preferentially takes <sup>16</sup>O relative to <sup>18</sup>O thus decreasing the <sup>16</sup>O/<sup>18</sup>O in ocean water (keep in mind we are talking about a ratio here).  During glacial periods, more water is taken out of the oceans and collected in glaciers which have a high <sup>16</sup>O/<sup>18</sup>O ratio.  Thus the ocean water during high glacial periods will be low in <sup>16</sup>O/<sup>18</sup>O.  Therefore during a period of no glaciation the <sup>16</sup>O/<sup>18</sup>O would be higher than today.  Or, in the silly way the questions states <sup>18</sup>O/<sup>16</sup>O  would be lower than today

Comment: The first part of your answer seems odd, as most of the classical works (e.g., Epstein & Mayeda, dx.doi.org/10.1016/0016-7037(53)90051-9) use the 18O/16O nomenclature. In fact the definition of delta-18O (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9418O) uses the ratio as stated in the question.